# Creating Spaces in Jut

Tags: juttle

Is there a way to create a space with Juttle via the [REST API](http://docs.jut.io/api-guide/#api-guide)? I understand that creating a space can be done in the dashboard, but I would like to know if it is possible to create one via an API.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something that we have yet exposed.  We are using this sort of thing in some variation internally for our QA needs and I am sure this will get fleshed out as our API's continues to evolve.

What sort of use case did you have in mind?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @Nekto, it's not this type of question you had in the mind when you reviewed it.